# COOKIE_DOMAIN and WP_CONTENT_URL creating issues in WP Site

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am using CDN by using sub domain and it is supposed to be cookie less. I have added following code in my wp-config :

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.subdomain/wp-content"); 
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "http://maindomain/");
```

This Causes issue in my wp site, First my new media files are not uploading and secondly now I am unable to login my admin panel. I getting that error while logging:
Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. Make sure you enable cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your wp-config file.

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "https://static.dominname.com"); define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.dominname.com");
```

Comment: I changed it but no luck